# NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log

Tags: java, slf4j

Getting this error everytime:

`Jul 24, 2017 4:41:35 AM org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter doHandle
WARNING: Exception or error caught by status service
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache.process(RequestAuthCache.java:76)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)`

Here's a quick `mvn dependency:tree`

```
mvn dependency:tree | find "slf4j"
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

Comment: Sounds like a library compatibility version problem. Is your project a Maven project? If so, run on root folder of your project: `mvn dependency:tree` and search for the slf4j dependencies.

Comment: I updated the question with the mvn log

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with the slf4j dependencies. My guess is that the `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog` is relaying in an newer version of the slf4j implementation. See it [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/jcl-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java) If you go back on the structure you will see that the pom file is 1.8 something alpha...